# numpy.correlate vs numpy documentation - is there a contradiction here ? Why is the resulting list reversed ?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I get the following result using numpy's correlate function:

```
In [153]: np.correlate([1],np.arange(100))
Out[153]:
array([99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83,
       82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66,
       65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49,
       48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32,
       31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15,
       14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])

In [154]:
```

This result seems to be in contradiction with the 90. page of the numpy [book](http://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/numpybook.pdf) :

[image]

Based on the formula above I would have expected an increasing array 0..99, however, the result is a decreasing array 99..0.

Can someone explain what is going on here ?

Why does the implementation contradicts the specification ?

Why does it make sense to reverse the list ?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are expecting the `old_behaviour` of [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html). The book you link to is very old (2006), so it looks like `numpy.correlate` has changed since it was written (it actually changed in [`numpy v1.4`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.4.0-notes.rst#deprecations)). From the [docs for `numpy v1.9`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html):

> old_behavior : bool
>
> If True, uses the old behavior from Numeric, (correlate(a,v) == correlate(v,a), and the conjugate is not taken for complex arrays). If False, uses the conventional signal processing definition.

```
In [2]: np.correlate([1],np.arange(100))
Out[2]: 
array([99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83,
   82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66,
   65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49,
   48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32,
   31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15,
   14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])

In [3]: np.correlate([1],np.arange(100),old_behavior=True)
Out[3]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
   51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
   68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
   85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])

In [4]: np.correlate(np.arange(100),[1])
Out[4]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
   51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
   68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
   85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```

**EDIT**

On further inspection, I think the difference is due to this line in the old definition:

> `K=len(x)-1` and `M=len(y)-1`, and we assume `K ≥ M` (without loss of generality because we can interchange the roles of `x` and `y` without effect).

So, I believe for your case, in the old definition, it is making `y=[1]` and `x=np.arange(100)`, because `len(x)` must be greater than `len(y)`. The new definition does not do that, instead ["input arrays are never swapped"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254067/588071), so `x=[1]` and `y=np.arange(100)`. Thus, the differences.

Comment: Thanks, so why is this strange behaviour then ? I mean, why does it makes sense to reverse the list ?

Comment: I don't think it is strange behaviour. Its just a matter of definition. In the old version, it expected the inputs in the reverse order (`v,a`), compared to the current version (`a,v`). It looks like the developers at some point realised the standard way in signal processing was to change the order to the current version

Comment: Well, the old behaviour does _not_ reverse the list no matter what the order is. I still don't get why the list reversal makes sense. In what context does that makes sense ? Why in Signal Processing does that make sense ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know the answer to that. But maybe [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251953/is-it-possible-that-numpy-correlate-does-not-follow-the-given-formula) might help you shed light on it. It looks like numpy v1.4 was when the definition changed (to, what they call, the _conventional_ correlation) - see the [release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.4.0-notes.rst#deprecations)

Comment: Also, see my edit for why you are getting the differences you see